# Running two loops simultaneously for a game - C

Tags: c, loops, simultaneous

I'm making a game in C for my programming class, and I have to place a time countdown on the game, but I can't make it work right, because if a put a countdown function and a delay(1000), it works for the countdown, but doesn't work for the game , because it makes wait the 1s every move.

My code so far is

```
while(tempo > 0)
{
    tempo_na_tela(&tempo);
    contador_tempo(&tempo);
    if(kbhit())
    {
        mover_refem(getch(), p_refem, &refem.px, &refem.py, 
                    numero_inimigos_na_tela(n, in1));
    }
    mover_inimigo(n, p_terrorista, in1);
}
```

The function `tempo_na_tela(..)` puts the string of time on the screen, the `contador_tempo(..)` is the countdown, the `mover_refem(...)` is the function to move the game character, and the `mover_inimigo(..)`is a function that randomly moves the enemy in the screen.

I need to place the `tempo_na_tela` and the `contador_tempo` functions in one loop, that run simultaneously with the other loop, that run the moving functions.

How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please try to style your code correctly (use the help in the editor if needed)

Comment: Sounds like you need to structure your program as an event loop.

Comment: "I need to place the tempo_na_tela and the contador_tempo functions in one loop" - Um, they're in *one loop* (the `while (tempo > 0)` construct). It at-least-seems the real problem is that `contador_tempo` *waits* for one second, thus stalling what this loop is intended to really do. If you can establish a start-time, calculate the expiration-time based on that, then detect when the *current time* has met or exceeded your expiration-time and break the loop accordingly, there would be no need to delay at all.

Answer (score 1):

You're experimenting a [**XY problem**](http://xyproblem.info/) i think.

**You don't need to run simultaneously thoses 2 functions.** What you're trying to accomplish is a game loop, it's very common in video-games, especially early ones.

Ask yourself, when do you need to re-paint your elements ? The answer is probably after having updated all of your data (Time, ennemy position, and having logged your player's movement)

So, you don't need simultaneous looping (ie thread i would have suggested, even if it's not true simultaneous, but that's another story.)

Instead, you can stick with one loop, but you have to do something in this fashion :

```
while (game_not_ended())
{
   update_data();
   repaint_data();
}
```

I hope you'll take the time to reconsider your code and the scope of your issue.